# GAE/J + Restlet + Backend + Cron Job + 405 Error:

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, restlet, http-status-code-405

Hoping to get some help or direction with the following issue I am facing.

I am getting a 405 (method not allowed) error when using GAE backends with a cron job on the live system.  The cron job started on the backend I defined, but it is throwing the 405 error after delegating the call to the target Restlet.  The url route is as follows as per the logs.

http://backendname.appid.appspot.com/cronURL

My current configuration is as follows:

- GAE/J: 1.6.1
- RESTLET: 2.1 RC5

I've have done the following:

- Defined the attachment of the cron url route to my java class in my Restlet application
- I have backends.xml defined

  - Set my backend as public to see if that resolves the issue, but it didn't
- I have cron.xml  defined

  - Set url for cron job
  - Set the target as my backend instance name

Please let me know if you would like more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you marked up your RESTlet with the @Get annotation?

A cron job will invoke the specified URL using an HTTP GET. Other verbs (e.g., PUT, POST, DELETE) are not supported by cron jobs.